# Module Not Found for config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting this error that says

```
Error: Cannot find module './config.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Sebas\source\repos\FunctionsLib\messages.js
- C:\Users\Sebas\source\repos\index.js
```

Now a little about my project, my project runs on Discordjs and am trying to make my project "modular", so I have my functions for chat management in another file, for example, a swear checker, the code of the swear checker is contained with another .js file called 'messages', and then is required in by the index.js which then, in turn, calls the functions, but also this messages.js file is requiring the index and the index is exposing variables so that the messages.js can read them. Right after I finished with this code. I kept getting the problem mentioned above, I restarted my PC thinking it was a problem with read and write perms. But I still get the problem, am 100% the location am mentioning for the config.json in both places is correct.

```
File structure:
C:.
│   .eslintrc.json
│   config.json
│   help.txt
│   index.js
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   words.json
│
├───FunctionsLib
│       messages.js
│
├───Logs
(The rest is node_modules)
```

Here is a link to my source code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z6cjPMZNWEQufbDn1ljNA5EdQNBFS698/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The directory structure is helpful but can you share your code? We don't know if your using require, import, or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the issue in `messages.js` which is inside of `FunctionsLib` directory.

To require files from higher directory you need to require it as `'../config.json'`

Comment: k, thanks. lol I only just realized I added my token there, gotta change it